# Using ASWing Haxe version to target android

Tags: android, haxe

I just checked out the Haxe version from http://svn.aswing.org/aswing/trunk/haXeAsWing/

And copied the org folder next to com folder of my project, if I target flash player in FlashDevelop, it will compile with no errors, but if I target android, I get those errors:

```
org/aswing/AWTextField.hx:58: lines 58-63 : Field set_htmlText should be declared with 'override' since it is inherited from superclass
org/aswing/AWTextField.hx:76: lines 76-83 : Field set_scrollH should be declared with 'override' since it is inherited from superclass
org/aswing/AWTextField.hx:85: lines 85-92 : Field set_scrollV should be declared with 'override' since it is inherited from superclass
org/aswing/AWTextField.hx:68: lines 68-73 : Field set_text should be declared with 'override' since it is inherited from superclass

org/aswing/Component.hx:1671: lines 1671-1673 : Field get_height should be declared with 'override' since it is inherited from superclass
org/aswing/Component.hx:641: lines 641-643 : Field get_visible should be declared with 'override' since it is inherited from superclass
```

Any idea? I have `NME 3.5.3` installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't help you with AsWing, but as you're into Android GUI stuff, I would really recommend checking out Ian Harrigan's YAHUI (https://github.com/ianharrigan/YAHUI). It's in heavy development, but looks very promising.

Comment: Have a look in the github repo issues conversations, and you'll see that Ian, the originator of YAHUI, is very frequent on feedback and adjustments this far.